# Python: make numpy array from ordered list [value, repeatedNumber]

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, repeat

What is the fastest way to convert a list `[[value, repeatedNo], ...]` to a 1D numpy array?

I have this so far:

```
import numpy as np    

bln = np.zeros(15)
counted_data = [[0,10],[1,2],[0,3]]
vrIndex =0

for vr in counted_data:
    if vr[0] == 0:
        vrIndex += vr[1]
    else:
        bln[vrIndex:vrIndex+vr[1]] =1
        vrIndex += vr[1]

print bln
```

Which prints:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
```

The problem is `bln` is 500,000 elements and I have to do this a 1000 different times, which is very slow.

I have also tried:

```
 bln = []
 for vr in counted_data:
     bln += list(Counter(dict([vr])).elements())
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest (and possibly one of the quickest) ways is to pass the data to [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
>>> np.repeat([0, 1, 0], repeats=[10, 2, 3])
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

If your data comes as a list of lists in the form of `counted_data`:

```
np.repeat(*zip(*counted_data))
```

Comment: `vals,repeats = zip(*counted_data)` might be better than he 2 list comprehensions though

Comment: If the values are only 0 and 1, is there a faster way than np.repeat(*zip(*counted_data)) ?

Comment: @AmarRampal: no faster way comes to mind. What kind of speed were you hoping for?